# Iterate over columns to produce ggplot using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I want to create multiple boxplots using for loop but having problems achieving the desired output.

Here as an example of what I have done:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
for(i in colnames(iris[1:4])) {
  print(iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = i)) + geom_boxplot())
}
```

It is performing a loop but the output is just flat boxplots. Am I incorrect in assuming that where I put `y = i`, that the `i` value takes on the name of the column name through the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are telling `ggplot` to set `y` to the *string* `"Sepal.Length"` (in the first iterattion), and `ggplot` does not translate that to the *column* `Sepal.Length`.

Thus, you need to tell `ggplot` explicitly that you want the column and there are a couple of ways to do that.

Two examples below. The first is using the `.data` pronoun,  which can be used in several places throughout the `tidyverse` to refer to the data.

The second option uses the quotation principles of the tidyverse.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
for(i in colnames(iris[1:4])) {
  dev.new()
  print(iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = .data[[i]])) + geom_boxplot())
  ## or
  # print(iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = !!sym(i))) + geom_boxplot()) 
}
```